# étale vs syntomic vs flat cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, cohomology, etale-cohomology, flat-cohomology

Let $\mathscr{A}/X$ be an abelian scheme over $X$ of characterisitic $p$. The étale topology is not fine enough for the Kummer sequence for $\mathscr{A}$ to be (right) exact, but the syntomic and flat topologies are. The flat topology is so fine that there are problems with finiteness theorems for flat cohomology, and it seems that the syntomic topology is in such a way coarser than the flat topology such that there are finiteness theorems.

> Can one explain how one (Mazur?) came up with the definition of the syntomic topology and why it is the "right" one?

Comment: The structure morphism for a commutative finite flat and finitely presented group scheme is more special than just an fppf map: it is syntomic!  This in turn is inherited by torsors for such. The reason this all works is by combining EGA IV$_4$ 19.3.4-19.3.6 and the structure of the coordinate ring of finite local commutative group schemes over a field (see 14.4 in Waterhouse's book on affine group schemes).

Comment: It's worth noting that flat (locally) finitely presented group schemes are syntomic (i.e. remove the 'finite' assumption here). A proof is in the second volume of Goertz-Wedhorn's AG book, in the chapter on abelian schemes Prop 27.26  (it's also somewhere in SGA 3 but harder to find there). As always, this proof also goes through by reduction to the case of a geometric point (by fpqc descent and fibralness of the criteria) where it follows from the structure theorem in eg. in Waterhouse's book. Note the statement in char 0 is trivial (since G is then smooth over S).